# Creating custom links from terms

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to create custom links for my Wordpress terms, I've done the following:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'blog' );                  
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
    $blog_links = array();
    $blog_slugs = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $blog_links[] = $term->name;
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $termslug ) {
        $blog_slugs[] = $termslug->slug;
    }   

    $blog = join( ", ", $blog_links );
    $blogs = join( ", ", $blog_slugs ); 
?>

<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog/<?php echo $blogs; ?>"><?php echo $blog; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This creates the url:

http://www.domain.com/blog/news,%20guest-blogs

With the text for the link looking like this (I.e it's making it all one link - see screenshot):

[image]

Which is close! I actually want to split each term up into a link (with a comma in between) and make the urls http://www.domain.com/blog/news and http://www.domain.com/blog/guest-blogs. I think I'm missing a `foreach` to output the each link separately.

Can someone help me get the final bit correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be easy to just use

`<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'blog', '', ', ', '' ); ?>`

---

something is wrong with your code... maybe something like this will do...

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'blog' );                  
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
    $blogs = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $blogs[] = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/blog/'. $term->slug .'">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }    

    $blog_links = join( ", ", $blogs);

    echo $blog_links;

endif; ?>
```

Comment: I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/teamwork/public_html/clients/rwcmd/wp-content/themes/default/single-blog.php on line 44`

Answer (score 0):

Your code just give only one output `a` element, you need to modify this snippet so that each element in `$terms` produces an `a` element with correct href and anchor. This maybe one solution

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'blog' );                  
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
    $output = array();
    foreach($terms as $term):
        // Use sprintf to quickly modify the template
        $output[] = sprintf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", get_bloginfo('url') . '/blog/' . $term->slug, $term->name);
    endforeach;
    echo implode(', ' $output); // This is the result
endif; 
?>
```